# higher moments of multivariate normal

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis

Suppose that $w,x,y,z$ follow four dimensional multivariate normal distribution 
$
(w,x,y,z)' \sim N(0, \Sigma)
$  with $\Sigma=\{\sigma_{jk}\}, (j,k=1,...,4)$

What are the expressions for $E(wxyz)$, $E(w^2xy)$ and $E(w^2y^2)$?

Comment: The mgf is your friend

Comment: Are there any useful reference that gives the exact expression of the results?

Comment: There must be prior solutions to this on statsSE but I cannot find them at the moment (no pun intended). This may help:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34779/how-to-efficiently-find-moments-of-a-multinormal-distribution/